# JavaScript functions on event handlers and issue with execution

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a question regarding why functions are called with `()` in some situations and not others. Take below for example. The test function is explicitly called by `test()` when the button is clicked.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="test()"/>
        <p id="p1">Test</p>

         <script>
          function test()
          {
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Whereas see below example:** The function is not called with `()` (i.e. its not immediately invoked). It simply called as `test` If I changed the below function to an anonymous function, it will work as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <input id = "b1" type="button" value="click"/>
    <p id="p1">Test</p>
     <script>

      function test()
      {

        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
      }
       var but = document.getElementById("b1");
       but.addEventListener("click", test, false);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason why in case of both event listeners (i.e. the on click event), one type does not require the parenthesis on the function call and the other does?

Comment: One is a function call (code which executes a function with no parameters) and the other is a function name.

Comment: The one without `()` isn't calling it. If you do `var foo = test`, does that call the function? It's basically doing the same thing as your `addEventListener`. In both cases, the function is assigned, one to a variable, the other to a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's different.

When you do `yourFunction()`, you're actually calling the function.

When you do `call(yourFunction)`, you're passing the function as a reference, and not executing it. It'll probably be executed later as a callback, like in event listeners.

Same thing as passing an anonymous function to another function, like

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){});
```

The anonymous function isn't called, it's only passed as a reference to the parameter inside the `addEventListener` function. It's later executed by the function it has been passed to.

You can also call functions using `yourFunction.call()` and `yourFunction.apply()` which allows you to change the meaning of `this` inside the function's context. jQuery passes the event target, for example.

This is why you're allowed to do this:

```
var yourFunction = function(){ alert('hey'); }
```

In this case, `yourFunction` is a variable of type `function`, which is the same that you'd get inside a function that has a `function` parameter.

You can then "execute" this variable trough `yourFunction()`, or the methods I mentioned above, and also pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Nice explanation, I was about to say something similar!

Comment: Thanks!, that helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Inline JS**

When you do an inline *onclick* handler like that, you're assigning a Javascript expression to run. So you need to execute the function.

The expression could just as easily be `onclick="test();alert(2)"` in which case its obvious that the function needs to be called, just like it would be if it were run from a javascript file.

**Binding a function to the click event**

If instead you attach the click event with javascript, you would be binding a function, so you just need to pass the function object.

```
var xyz = document.getElementById("btn");
xyz.addEventListener("test",handler);
```

addEventListener sets the function object to be bound to the event so that it executes when the event is triggered. Since you're specifying a function object, rather than a string expression, the parentheses are not needed. In fact if you added them the function would execute immediatelly and the return value of the function would be bound to the event.